# TypeError: Cannot set property '_eventListeners' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Getting below error while running the tests using React + jest + Enzyme, please help!

*● Test suite failed to run 

        TypeError: Cannot set property '_eventListeners' of undefined

          at Window.close (E:/TEST-UI/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:498:51)

              at Generator.throw ()*

The error is weird! even I tried to setup the jsdom like below but nothing worked!

```
const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
```

**Below are are code snippets.**

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'jsdom-global/register';
import "isomorphic-fetch";


Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

export * from 'enzyme';
```

test:

```
import React from "react";
import Notification from "./Notification";
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import "src/config/jsdom.setup";

describe('<Notification />', () => {
    test("always renders notificationCount", () => {
        let wrapper = shallow(<Notification/>);
        const divs = wrapper.find("div");
        expect(divs.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

    });
});
```

>

```
require('babel-register')();

const jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;

Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach(property => {
    if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
        exposedProperties.push(property);
        global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
    }
});

global.navigator = {userAgent: 'node.js'};
```

package.json snippet:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^11.12.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

For JSDOM, are you supposed to specify the object in the DOM that you're accessing? Where you have `global.document = jsdom('');` might be causing the errors. Should you be pointing it at the window or the document instead? In situations like this, where the node module is the one throwing the error, it's usually either due to not being implemented correctly, or due to some incompatibility. My guess in this case is the former. While I don't know the library in question, my experience with things like this tells me that it's probably not being implemented right.

One other thing I would recommend looking at would be your looping method. Doing `Object.keys().forEach()` seems messy and inefficient, when you can probably just as easily do a simpler `for` loop--something along the lines of:

```
for (let property in document.defaultView) {
  if (document.defaultView.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if I do it as below it throws same error.***********

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>'); <BR/>
const window = jsdom;